# How Do You Halt The Current Programs "Progress" at A JPanel/JFrame Pop Up?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

Whenever I open a JOptionPane.showInputDialog, the program I am writing comes to a "halt" and it waits for input. Or if I have a message dialog, the program halts and waits for the user to click Ok before proceeding with the rest of the code.

I created a JPanel that displays a picture and a button, however, when I run it and it shows set visible equal to "true", the JPanel appears, however, the program continues to run anyway down the other lines of code and does not stop.

Is it necessary to create listeners or boolean's in order to halt the program's current progress until an action is taken on the JPanel/JPane, or is there a simple way for the program to wait for a user's response to a JPanel/Jpane before proceeding?

Comment: You  can add a panel to a JOptionPane, or you can create a modal JDialog.

Comment: [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Comment: I am familar with these dialog boxes, but they do not do what I need. For example, I need to display a JPG image and then a button and have the program stop. These dialog boxes seem very structured in that you have to do exactly what is in there, you can't edit them. That's why I made a JPanel and put a JPanel inside a JFrame, but I cannot make it stop there. Do you know what I am saying?

Comment: Why not simply put your JPanel into a modal JDialog? You'd do this just the same as you'd do with a JFrame. Understand that any *complex* JPanel GUI can go into a JOptionPane or JDialog, or JFrame just the same. And yes, we know what you're saying and then some, please trust us.

Comment: I don't understand when you  say put it into a JDialog? A JDialog I thought had to be a certain type of box, like a message box or an input box?

Comment: A JDialog is **very similar to** a JFrame except that it can be modal -- just what you want. Please read the JDialog API entry.

Comment: is every JDialog modal? I attempted to add it, but it still is not filtering through all the way.

Comment: The example posted above is a JOptionPane.. I don't need a JOptionPane, I have my own JFrame and JPanel that is placed inside the JFrame.

Comment: No, you have to set it to be modal. For instance, if you call the constructor with your JFrame, it could look like: `new JDialog(myJFrame, "Title String", ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);`

Comment: okay thanks, let me try that. this layout stuff is driving me nuts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76492/discussion-between-simon-and-hovercraft-full-of-eels).